# wxPython: How can I listen to EVT_CHAR events on a multiline TextCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am able to successfully listen to EVT_CHAR events on a TextCtrl but when I change the TextCtrl to use TE_MULTILINE then the binding seems to stop working.

```
self.input = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
self.input.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnChar)
```

I am using 3.0.3.dev1820+49a8884 osx-cocoa (phoenix).

How can I listen to EVT_CHAR events on a multiline TextCtrl?

Comment: thats weird ... do you really need EVT_CHAR? are you sure EVT_TEXT wont be good enough? or EVT_KILL_FOCUS?

Comment: I might be able to use EVT_TEXT instead. That one seems to work fine.

Comment: wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN would probably work also just so you know ... no idea as to why EVT_CHAR doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code exhibited in the question *should* work, and *does* if you're not on a Mac. The fact that it doesn't work on Macs is a bug - I reported it at https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/804 and it's confirmed by the maintainers.

The bug will be fixed in wxPython 4.1, which at the time of writing is not yet released.

If you have to use a version of wxPython that doesn't have the fix, then depending upon your objectives it *may* be adequate to bind to `wx.EVT_TEXT` or `wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN` instead, although neither has quite the same behaviour as `wx.EVT_CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your problem. Here's the working code that I modified from [the Mouse vs the Python blog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/29/wxpython-catching-key-and-char-events/). I only changed the style of text control to wx.TE_MULTILINE and it still works on Windows7 (wxPython2.8.12.1). Could it be a Phoenix bug?

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Char Event Tutorial")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        btn = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value="", style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.onCharEvent)

    def onCharEvent(self, event):
        keycode = event.GetKeyCode()
        controlDown = event.CmdDown()
        altDown = event.AltDown()
        shiftDown = event.ShiftDown()

        print keycode
        if keycode == wx.WXK_SPACE:
            print "you pressed the spacebar!"
        elif controlDown and altDown:
            print keycode
        event.Skip()


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Could be an OSX specific issue.